# Code supposed to get integer value from innerHTML of input field returning NaN

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, innerhtml

I am working on a password generator. Basically I'm trying to include an input field where users can input any number to set a character count (e.g. 5 = 5 character-long password etc.), but instead of returning a number the onclick event listener on the "go" button returns NaN.
Here are the HTML and JS code snippets relevant to my question, tysm in advance for the help :)

```
<input id = "ccount"> </input>
<button id = "go"> go </input>

document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", function(){
  let ccount = parseInt(document.getElementById("ccount").innerHTML)
  console.log(ccount) //convert into integer value the innerHTML of the input field and store it in the ccount variable, as soon as the "go" button is pressed.

})
```

Comment: To get the value of an `<input>` you use `.value`, not `.innerHTML`.

Comment: There's no such thing as `</input>` and you want the `value` not the `innerHTML`

Comment: thanks, closing <button> with </input> was a distraction error

Comment: You don't close a regular input with `</input>` All you need is `<input>`, it closes itself.